# Error implementing Byte-Buddy proxy in Glassfish eviroment

Tags: java, glassfish, classloader, byte-buddy

I'am couldn't implement a BB proxy inside a Glassfish server. When I try to use the generated class it throws:

```
Grave:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error invoking java.lang.ClassLoader#findClass
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Resolved.loadClass(ClassInjector.java:401)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection.inject(ClassInjector.java:210)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$InjectionDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:204)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:119)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4350)
at ar.gov.santafe.mpa.odbogm.proxy.ObjectProxyFactory.create(ObjectProxyFactory.java:77)
```

Here is the method class that generate the proxy object:

```
public static <T> T create(T o, OrientElement oe, SessionManager sm ) {
    T po = null;
    try {
        ObjectProxy bbi = new ObjectProxy(o,oe,sm);
        po = (T) new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(o.getClass())
                .implement(IObjectProxy.class)
//                   .method(isDeclaredBy(IObjectProxy.class))
                    .method(any())
                    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(bbi))
                .make()
                .load(o.getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION)
                .getLoaded().newInstance();
        bbi.___setProxyObject(po);

    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ObjectProxyFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ObjectProxyFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return po;
}
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tuqjv0ljltrzg1p/bb-glassfish-stacktrace.txt?dl=0) is the full stack trace.

Note: the code work fine and pass all test in the stand-alone jvm.

---

It's the classloader of Glassfish! I could not get it to load the class from the WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: The exception should have a cause attached for why the execition failed. What does the cause indicate?

Comment: It say that the IObjectProxy class is not found, but that class is in the package that it reference. 
Could be a problem with the package? The OGM package is diferent than the app package.

Comment: I have upload the project to Github for anyone who want to inspect/use it. The url is https://github.com/mdre/odbogm

Comment: I cannot currently build the project, I am on vacation but it seems like a class loader issue to me. The IObjectProxy class seems to be loaded by a class loader that is not visible to that of o.getClass().

Comment: Thanks. I have finished the upload to GH and tomorrow will investigate the classloader problem.

Comment: Well, back again. The problem persist. Glassfish report that the ClassLoader is CL: WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)
Well, back again. The problem persist. Glassfish report that the ClassLoader is CL: WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)
The class is in WEB-INF/lib and the app is currently using libraries in that path, but it is not loading IObjectProxy interface.

Comment: I have added the CGLib stub and it work. Why? What I must do to implement in the same way the object interceptor with BB?

Comment: Try using a wrapper strategy instead of injection. I assume thst it is some particularly with the glassfish class loader. This comes closer to what cglib does.

Comment: Similar error. Other classes in BB but it still NoClassDefFoundError: net/odbogm/proxy/IObjectProxy.

Answer (score 0):

The class loader of `o.getClass()` cannot see `IObjectProxy`, the error that you encounter is similar to calling:

```
Class.forName(IObjectProxy.class.getName(), 
              false,
              o.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

what seems not to be possible in your Glassfish setup. You have different solutions:

1. Make sure that `IObjectProxy` is visible to `o.getClass().getClassLoader()` by configuring your project in that way.
2. If `IObjectProxy.class.getClassLoader()` is a child of `o.getClass().getClassLoader()`, use this class loader instead.
3. Define a `MultipleParentClassLoader` (part of Byte Buddy) that is a child of both class loaders to load the instrumented class. You can do so by calling:

   ```
   new MultipleParentClassLoader.Builder()
       .append(IObjectProxy.class, o.getClass())
       .build();
   ```